# Limit of a inverse matrix with entries tending to zero

Tags: matrices, limits, inverse

Let $A\in R^{n\times n}$ (symmetric), I know that, $\forall(i,j)$  $\lim_{x\to\infty} a_{ij}(x)=0$, .

I want to show, if possible, that the $$\lim_{x\to\infty} A^{-1}=E,$$ where $E$ is a $n\times n$ matrix with all the entries equal to $\infty$.

We know that the inverse is a continuous map, we have that  $\lim_{x\to\infty} A^{-1}=(\lim_{x\to\infty} A)^{-1}$. Any ideas of how to follow?

Comment: How about the matrix $A=\pmatrix{1/x&-1/x^2\\1/x^2&1/x}$?

Answer (score 3):

This is not right. Consider the matrices
$$
A_k =
\begin{pmatrix}
1/k & 1/k^2 \\
1/k^2 & 1/k
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then
$$
A_k^{-1} = \frac{k^2}{k^2-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
k & -1 \\
-1 & k
\end{pmatrix}
\to
\begin{pmatrix}
+ \infty & -1 \\
-1 & + \infty
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Overlapped with the solution in the comment (+ symmetry).

Comment: I wonder which assumptions we could make to assure the result, maybe some assumption on the determinant of A?